# Cost comparison using Solr

Tags: lucene, comparison, solr, sphinx, solrj

I plan to build something like pricegrabber.com/google product search.

Assume I already have the data available in a huge table. I plan to submit this all to Solr. This solves the problem of search. However I am not sure how to do comparison. I can do a group by query(on UPC/SKU) for the products returned by Solr on the DB. However, I dont want to do that. I want to somehow get product comparison data returned to me along with search from Solr itself.

How do you think should my schema be? Do you think this use-case can be solved all by Solr/Sphinx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 'result grouping' or 'field collapsing' support to properly handle it.

In **Solr**, the feature is not available in any release version and is still under development. If you are willing to use an unreleased version of Solr, then get the details [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).

**Sphinx** supports result grouping and I had used it a long time ago in a similar project. You can get more details [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/clustering.html).

An alternative strategy could be to preprocess your data so that only a single record per UPC/SKU gets inserted in the index. Each record can have a separate field containing the ids of all the items with the same UPC/SKU.

Doing a database GROUP BY on the products returned by Solr may not be enough. For example, if products A and B have the same UPC and a certain query matches A but not B, then you will not get both A and B in your result set.